# Design pattern to optimize ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, performance, dom, design-patterns

I am trying to get the DOM elements of an angular component through a querySelectorAll method, like this:

```
const widgetHTMLElements: NodeListOf<ChildNode> = document.querySelectorAll('medium-editor')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes
```

My first instinct was to put it in the ngAfterViewInit method, but I was soon to realize the DOM was not ready yet, I know so because I've displayed some console.log(s) and I got the following:

[image]

What's interesting here is that the NodeList returned has a length **zero** yet contains some elements, I thought at first it's a mere Chrome console inconsistency, but once I've tried to loop over the object, I'd notice it's not working, so I wonder what's up with angular with that regard...

Anyways, I though it might have to do lifecycle-hooks and went for the *ngAfterViewChecked*, the good news is that it works fine, I can loop through the returned NodeList and console.log shows something more interesting:

[image]

Clearly there's an iteration where the old state of DOM is prevalent, then the first change lets the querySelectorAll return the desired objects.

The thing is ngAfterViewChecked will execute indefinitely, so I thought I might establish some boolean flag which sets to true once the length of querySelectorAll changes or something; I just don't want to ngAfterViewChecked to continue eating resources while the page is mostly idle, but I don't want to miss significant changes either.

My question is about whether there exists some Design pattern to limit performance issues with ngAfterViewChecked, if so, what does it look like?

Comment: If you are interested in DOM hierarchy changes, why don't you go for MutationObserver?

Comment: @CuriousMind: probably because I ignored their existence, lol. After reading up on MDN it seems to be doing whatever the Zone change detection does for Angular, but it's definitely something to explore on some side project, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, it should have DOM populated after `ngAfterViewInit` method is called. I'm not sure, whether the DOM you're keeping eye on is populated based on `async` API call.

The reason behind `ngAfterViewChecked` is called after default change detector has completed checking a component's view for changes. Rather than using `document.querySelectorAll`, I would recommend you to use `ViewChildren`.

```
// I'm assuming below `menu-editor` is component selector
@ViewChildren('medium-editor') mediumEditors: QueryList<MenuEditorComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.mediumEditors.changes.subscribe((mediumEditors) => {
      console.log('mediumEditors', mediumEditors);
      // use nativeElement property of each item to access DOM
      mediumEditors.forEach(i => console.log(i.nativeElement));
   });
}
```

Over here you can keep eye on `menuEditors` DOM element, in an angular way. Any changes in `menu-editor`'s element addition/removal will be emitted inside `change` subscription.

Comment: +1, this looks the clearnest way of doing it indeed, I should've thought about it :p
Otherwise, yes there are some API calls changing the states of the components, but what's strange is that we get their content (as displayed in the first picture), it's just weird how the DOM does not seem to follow-up. Thanks for the reply!